# How do I read resource files in different packages?

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to read the "User.json" file from class "UserList.java", but I can not. I am developing in JSP / Servlet and I do not like reading in the context of server folders (TOMCAT).

I try it:

**// User.java**

```
Gson gsonObject = new Gson();
String res = gsonObject.toJson(new FileReader("User.json"));

System.out.println("User ==> JSON  " + res);
```

**Result:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: User.json
```

Json file:

**// User.json**

```
{
    "user": {
        "type": "text"
        },
    "name": {
        "type": "text"
        },
    "password": {
        "type": "password"
    },
    "characterName": { 
        "type": "combo",
        "id": "rolls"
    }
}
```

**The packages are as follows:**

br.com.servtech.servlet.list ==> UserList.java 
 br.com.servtech.model.json ==> User.json

Comment: Where did you put this file? Are you sure the path you give as parameter is correct? It might help you to use an absolute path

Comment: The packages are as follows:

br.com.servtech.servlet.list ==> UserList.java
br.com.servtech.model.json ==> User.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FileReader` constructor takes a **file** name as argument. You pass it a relative file name, so Java is looking for it on the file system, in its current directory, which is the directory from which the java command used to start Tomcat was launched.

Not only the path is thus incorrect, but you don't even want to use a **file**, since what you want to read is a **resource** which is inside the war file, or even inside a jar file inside the war file.

You want to use this resource thanks to the class loader, since this resource must be found using the same loading mechanisms, based on wars and jars and packages, as .class files. You thus should use

```
InputStream in = UserList.class.getResourceAsStream("/br/com/servtech/model/json/User.json");
```

Comment: **Great!**
Thank you JB Nizet!